# Checking an input for characters $@!%&*_ python

Tags: python-3.x

No i'm not cursing in the title. i need to create a password processing program that checks a input on whether it meets certain criteria one of which is that it must contain one of the characters $@!%&*_. 
this is what i currently have.

```
def pword():
    global password
    global lower
    global upper
    global integer

password = input("Please enter your password ")
length = len(password)
lower = sum([int(c.islower()) for c in password])
upper = sum([int(c.isupper()) for c in password])
integer = sum([int(c.isdigit()) for c in password])


def length():
    global password
if len(password) < 8:
    print("Your password is too short, please try again")
elif len(password) > 24:
    print("Your password is too long, please try again")

def strength():
    global lower
    global upper
    global integer
if (lower) < 2:
    print("Please use a mixed case password with lower case letters")
elif (upper) < 2:
    print("Please use a mixed case password with UPPER case letters")
elif (integer) < 2:
    print("Please try adding numbers")
else:
    print("Strength Assessed - Your password is ok")
```

Comment: You can use `re.match(...)` in the `re` module of the standard library.  Note that some of the symbols you're matching against have a different meaning in the context of a regular expression, so be sure to escape them -- for example in match use `'\*'` to find a literal `*` vs. `'*'` to mean "0 or more repetitions".  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: By the way, you don't need to declare `global foo` for variables inside functions unless you're modifying them -- they already have read access to global per [the rules of scope resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/149428).  You could remove all of your global decorations inside `length()` and `strength()`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing will work:

```
required='$@!%&*_'

def has_required(input):
    for char in required:
        if input.contains(char):
            return True
    return False

has_required('Foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
must_have = '$@!%&*_'
if not any(c in must_have for c in password):
    print("Please try adding %s." % must_have)
```

`any(c in must_have for c in password)` will return True if any one of the characters in `password` is also in `must_have`, in other words, it will return True is the password is good.  Because want to test for bad passwords, we put `not` in front of it to reverse the test.  Thus the `print` statement is executed here only for bad passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with a list comprehension + the [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in.

```
has_symbol = any([symbol in password for symbol in list('$@!%&*_')])
```

Or a little more broken up:

```
required_symbols = list('$@!%&*_')
has_symbol = any([symbol in password for symbol in required_symbols])
```